# OpenCV: Prepare angle-based kernel for erosion

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filtering, mathematical-morphology

I have an image that contains several straight lines at various angles (e.g. horizontal, vertical, diagonal, cross-diagonal). I have a code that can filter the lines in a desired direction since I know how to set a kernel matrix for horizontal, vertical, diagonal, and cross-diagonal directions. However, for lines at an arbitrary angle, I have no clue how to do it. See my code below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 

# Define a image display function to work on Jupyter notebook 
def showimage(title,myimage):
    # Reverse OpenCV's BGR order to RGB for colored images (ndim>2)
    if (myimage.ndim>2):  
        myimage = myimage[:,:,::-1]  
         
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
    ax.imshow(myimage, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # hide tick values on X and Y axes
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
    

# Load the image
imfile = 'multilines.jpg' # working image file
image = cv2.imread(imfile)  
showimage('Original',image)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply Canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)


### Erosion: 
# Create a horizontal kernel for erosion
kernel_h = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)


# Create a vertical kernel for erosion
kernel_v = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)



# Create a diagonal kernel for erosion (45 degrees)
kernel_d = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)


# Create a cross-diagonal kernel for erosion (45 degrees)
kernel_crossd = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                     [0, 1, 0],
                     [1, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)


kernel = kernel_h; tag = 'Horizontal'
kernel = kernel_v; tag = 'Vertical'
kernel = kernel_d; tag = 'Diagonal'
kernel = kernel_crossd; tag = 'Cross-diagonal'


# TO DO begins ----------------------
# Create a generic angle dependent kernel 
theta = 90
theta = np.deg2rad(theta)

## kernel_angle =  ? <- Here to uncomment and modify
## kernel = kernel_angle ; tag = 'Generic angle-based' # Uncomment once modify above

# TO DO ends ------------------------


print(f'{tag} erosion applied.')

# Apply erosion to isolate desired lines
erosion_lines = cv2.erode(edges, kernel, iterations=1)
showimage('After erosion',erosion_lines)


# Invert the colors (convert to negative to get white background)
result = cv2.bitwise_not(erosion_lines)

# Show final image
showimage('Final',result)
```

**How can I create a generic kernel that creates filters for any arbitrarily angled line?** This will also reduce the tedious task of assigning the kernel of each type of line (e.g. horizontal, vertical, diagonal, etc).

The "TO DO" part needs to get modified. Any solution?

I using this image (filename: 'multilines.jpg') :

[image]

Output image:
[image]

Comment: you want that for 3x3 kernels? that is unreasonable. -- what is the goal? explain what problem you're trying to solve with all this. -- if you're looking to scan barcodes in a 2d image, *one* approach is to "rake" over the image (warpAffine) like you would with actual lasers, in several parallel passes per direction. it suffices to do that for directions 0 and 90 degrees, as well as 45 and 135 degrees (the diagonals). -- or _locate_ the barcodes first (morphology ops may help), get bounding boxes, then sample along the major midline of each bounding box. sampling can be done with warpAffine()

Comment: Why is that unreasonable? Could you elaborate? I think any (x,y,z) coordinate can be parametrized by a constant (r) and an angle theta. The goal is to detect lines in a particular direction (e.g. scanning roads from a map). I think it is clear in my question and the code.

Comment: A 3x3 binary kernel has too few pixels to represent arbitrary angles -- only horizontal, vertical and the two diagonals.  You would be best to determine the angle of the lines and rotate the image to horizontal or vertical, do your processing and if desired rotate it back at the end.

Comment: "scanning roads from a map" warrants further description. we can't help if you won't tell us the real task. when explaining, always ask yourself "...and *what* do I need to do _that_ for?" after every answer. -- those random barcodes sent me down the wrong track. if you are not dealing with barcodes, please state that clearly, and perhaps find an _actual representative_ example of your problem.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Do you want to identify lines at a very specific angle? Say I pick angle 12.8349. Do you want to find lines of that angle within 0.0001 degrees? Or more approximately, say within 1 degree or 5 degrees? Or is it lines in the general cardinal direction, so within a 45 or 90 degree cone from a cardinal direction? Or do you want to identify lines at any angle, but you’re asking for a specific angle because you already know how to identify lines at cardinal directions (ie this is an [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. My 'X' is OpenCV and my 'Y' is to filter out images at any given direction and I believe angle is the best way to mark a direction. Now, what you're asking is a matter of precision. The higher the precision, the happier I might become. No, it's not for only cardinal directions. I may have an image that is bordered by lines in different directions. I want to capture them individually. Once I filter out a line at a given angle, I can easily interpolate it (since I set up a straight line for that angle). Hope I am clearer than before.

Comment: “The higher the precision, the happier I might become.” So you know the exact angle ahead of time? And you want to identify a line at  23.562 degrees and ignore one at 23.563 degrees?

Comment: “I may have an image that is bordered by lines in different directions.” Wouldn’t you then need to identify all lines at all angles? So you can then isolate these lines bordering your image?

Comment: If I detect all the lines in one shot, how can I determine each one's angle? I need to know the existence of different legs at different positions before I infer an elephant is a four-legged animal. I need to filter one by one.

Comment: So what is your plan? Filter the image at each possible angle, and hope two lines don’t have the same angle? I don’t think this is the right approach. You probably want to first identify all lines, then separate them out into individual straight lines. There are many ways you could do that. For example you could use the Hough transform, if you know that your lines are always perfectly straight (eg no lens distortion causing straight lines to curve).

Comment: "You probably want to first identify all lines, then separate them out into individual straight lines" - That's okay with me. Hough transform only detects lines. What's next?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the sobel filter manually in order get access to the (local) orientation of an edge as described on [Wikipedia about Sobel filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Formulation).

```
image = cv2.imread(imfile)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# applying sobel filter manually to get access to the angle

sobel_x = np.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
sobel_y = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])

x = sig.convolve2d(gray, sobel_x)
y = sig.convolve2d(gray, sobel_y)

angle = np.arctan2(y,x)

# bringing range from [-np.pi, np.pi] to [0, 2*np.pi]
angle = angle + np.pi
```

The resulting array of angles can then be filtered with respect to the angle(s) of interest.

```
# filtering; 30 +/- 5 ° chosen as an example
target = 30
upper = np.pi / 180 * (target + 5)
lower = np.pi / 180 * (target - 5)

target_img = np.where(angle < upper, angle, 0)
target_img = np.where(target_img > lower, angle, 0)


cv2.imshow('angle', (target_img) / np.max(target_img))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain why you need to normalize the `target_img`? The code apparently filters out lines at a given angle out of 45, 90, and 135 degrees. However, it poorly performs for 180 degrees and fails for 0 and any angle with negative degrees. Secondly, it contains lots of noise or grains with a black background while in my code, the output image was quite clean with white background.

Comment: Maybe I need to rotate and use cardinal filters as recommended by others. I have added the output image now in the original question.